# ionic 3 youtube api data

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, youtube-data-api

I'm having a problem calling the data into the view. Console log is working as I included a screenshot.

```
ytapiUrl =https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems? part=snippet&playlistId='blahblahbla'

getECvideolists(){
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.httpClient.get(this.ytapiUrl).subscribe(ytdata => {
    resolve(ytdata);
    this.Ecvideos = ytdata;
    console.log(ytdata);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

}

```
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'videos'">
<ion-item *ngFor="let Ecvideo of Ecvideos"> 

<h2> ***this doesn't display*** {{Ecvideo.items.snippet.title}}</h2>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

[image: results of getvideolist in console]

[image: Correct number of results but no titles]

[[image: console log[3]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

items key has an array so you need to iterate it through *ngFor

for example,

```html
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'videos'">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of Ecvideos.items">
    <h2>{{item.snippet.title}}</h2> 
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: That is alot closers then I got in hours, so thanks ALOT. But it is returning the correct number of results but not showing the titles.@Drs I including a new screenshot above.

Comment: great, I have updated code snippets please try with new code

Comment: So based on the information you provide "items key has an array so you need to iterate it through *ngFor". Snippet key also has an array. So I have to iterate that also?

Comment: i don't think Snippet key has an array, but if it is then yes need to iterate that

Comment: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. With the updated code

Comment: Ecvideos is an array or object?

Comment: if Ecvideos is obejct then you need to try this snippest.

<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'videos'">
<ion-item *ngFor="let items of Ecvideos.items"> 
    <h2> ***this doesn't display*** {{item.snippet.title}}</h2>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>

Comment: Ecvideos is an array? based on console log screenshot in my original post.  Sorry, I'm new and learning.  Thank you for your patience.

Comment: No problem, I am not able to see complete hierarchy of the object in screenshot.
try this snippet.


<ion-list ngSwitchCase="'videos'"> <ion-item *ngFor="let items of Ecvideos.items"> <h2>{{item.snippet.title}}</h2> </ion-item> </ion-list>

Comment: can you make a new screenshot that show object hierarchy?

Comment: I placed it with the other images

Comment: sorry i have spelling mistake, 
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of Ecvideos.items"> <h2>{{item.snippet.title}}</h2> </ion-item>

Comment: YOU GOT IT!   Thank you so much for your help.